# Update data only if user change anything in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Update data only if the user changes anything otherwise return a message that nothing to update. After click the edit button, if the user hits update button without change anything then return message nothing to update.
If the user changes anything in the edit form then it will be updated.

I tried with this

```
( I have multiple fields. This is for demo)
   
    if ($user->name == $request->name && $user->email == $request->email && $user->contact == 
       $request>contact) {
            return back()->with('info', 'You have not change anything. Nothing to update!');

        } else {
            $user->update([
                'name'    => $request->name,
                'email'   => $request->email,
                'contact' => $request->contact,
                'image'   => $image,
            ]);

        }
        return redirect()->route('admin.home')->with('success', 'Profile has been updated');
```

That work's fine except image.

Here is my image upload process

```
 if ($request->has('image')) {
     Storage::delete('public/avatar/users/' . $user->image);
      $image_name = hexdec(uniqid());
      $ext  = strtolower($request->image->getClientOriginalExtension());
      $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext;
      $request->image->storeAs('avatar/users/', $image_full_name, 'public');
      $image = $image_full_name;
        } else {
            $image = $user->image;
        }
```

How can I do this with image? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What is `$image` and `$user->$image`? A path?

Comment: $image    =$request->image,

Comment: Okay then what is `$request->image`? A path to the image on the server?

Comment: no, image that comes from edit form

Comment: Please post the code the handles the image upload process, since we can not determine if you are using a LOB or handling the upload and moving it to a path such as using the original file name,`uniqid()` or if it's just a URL, etc.

Comment: I updated my post, added my image upload process

Comment: Since you are persisting the image name as a string to the database and you delete the original image prior `Storage::delete('public/avatar/users/' . $user->image);`, the image can't be verified as having been changed. You would have to compare them prior to deleting the current image.

Comment: I know this is the reason that image is verified. Can you tell me the way how to compare with image if it is updated or not?

Answer (score 0):

Since Eloquent can track changes made to the model, I recommend using [Model Attribute Examinations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes) to then determine if the model [`::wasChanged()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/8.x/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php).

As your original script processes an uploaded file and persisted the `$user->image` as string to the database, you need to compare the uploaded file source with the current image file source (if any), to determine if the image changes should be applied.

```php
if ($request->has('image')) {
    //only check image if supplied
    if (!$user->image || sha1_file(Storage::path('public/avatar/users/' . $user->image)) !== sha1_file($request->image->path())) {
        //apply image changes
        if ($user->image) {
            //remove previous image
            Storage::delete('public/avatar/users/' . $user->image);
        }
        $image = str_replace('.', '', uniqid('', true)) . '.' . strtolower($request->image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $request->image->storeAs('avatar/users/', $image, 'public');
        $user->fill(['image' => $image]);
    }
}
$user->fill([
    'name'    => $request->name,
    'email'   => $request->email,
    'contact' => $request->contact,
]);
$user->save();
if ($user->wasChanged(['name', 'email', 'contact', 'image'])) {
    return redirect()->route('admin.home')->with('success', 'Profile has been updated');
}

return back()->with('info', 'You have not change anything. Nothing to update!');
```

### Disclaimer

I do not recommend using `hexdec(uniqid())`, in favor of directly using `uniqid('', true)`. As the usage of `hexdec()` will ignore any non-hexadecimal characters it encounters and may cause undesired results or loss of data.

Example: https://3v4l.org/aFGEJ

```php
var_dump(hexdec("See"));
var_dump(hexdec("ee"));
// both print "int(238)"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$updatedUser = $user->update([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'contact' => $request->contact,
    'image' => $image,
]);
if (serialize($user) == serialize($updatedUser)) {
   // user has updated something
} else {
  // no changes were made
}
```

Comment: I applied your way,  if I change something then I got this // no changes were made , If I not change anything then also get this // no changes were made

Comment: @ihprince The logic is also inverted, if the two values are equal then nothing was changed. Your result is caused by [`->update()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L776) and [`->save()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L832) return a boolean value.  So `serialize(object) == serialize(bool)` will always be `false`.